# How to use `dns-sd` to discover all domains with specific TLD?

Tags: macos, tld, dns-sd

I'm trying to discover all domains with the TLD *.ffhh*. This is the TLD of the Freifunk Meshnetwork in Hamburg. I tried the following command in Mac Terminal:

`dns-sd -B _http._tcp ffhh.`

I get this output, but nothing happens after that:

`Browsing for _http._tcp.ffhh.
DATE: ---Thu 23 Jul 2015---
10:40:20.934  ...STARTING...`

I guess I'm using dns-sd wrong!? What would be the right command to discover all domains with this TLD?

Answer (score 4):

I do not think you can use `dns-sd` to browse top level domains. (And if you really can -- *I'm not sure about this!* -- then your command would be correct. It just does not find any result for that TLD. See my further answer...)

Also, browsing for _http._tcp in a certain domain will only display results, if there actually is a HTTP service that is *announced* via DNS-SD in that domain.

#### 1. *`dns-sd`* is for *`local.`* domain in the first place

To test it, you can run `dns-sd -R` in one terminal to announce a fake HTTP service:

```
 dns-sd  \
   -R "A Fake Announcement to Register a Dummy HTTP Server" \
   _http._tcp,_universal \
   .   \
   8081
```

and then check if the announcement appears in the local browse list:

```
 dns-sd -B _http._tcp
```

#### 2. *`dns-sd`* works also for remote domains ... under certain conditions

To check for announced services in a remote domain, try:

```
 dns-sd -B _ftp._tcp dns-sd.org.
```

You should see something like

```
Browsing for _ftp._tcp.dns-sd.org.
DATE: ---Thu 19 May 2016---
17:40:02.111  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R  Flags  if Domain        Service Type  Instance Name
17:40:02.112  Add      3   0 dns-sd.org.   _ftp._tcp.    Apple QuickTime Files
17:40:02.112  Add      3   0 dns-sd.org.   _ftp._tcp.    Microsoft Developer Files
17:40:02.112  Add      2   0 dns-sd.org.   _ftp._tcp.    Restricted, Registered Users Only
^C
```

Then you can resolve a specific instance by running another command:

```
dns-sd -L "Microsoft Developer Files" _ftp._tcp dns-sd.org.

  Lookup Microsoft Developer Files._ftp._tcp.dns-sd.org.
  DATE: ---Thu 19 May 2016---
  17:40:43.972  ...STARTING...
  17:40:44.365  Microsoft\032Developer\032Files._ftp._tcp.dns-sd.org. can be reached at ftp.microsoft.com.:21 (interface 0)
   txtvers=1
   path=/developer
^C
```

#### 3. So why did browsing the remote *`dns-sd.org.`* domain work at all?

This is because Stuart Cheshire, the guy who "invented" DNS-SD and who runs the *dns-sd.org* domain, did ***register*** the FTP services in his own domain ***within his standard DNS server setup*** in with the appropriate means.

#### 4. So why does *`dns-sd.org`* return records about a Microsoft-controlled FTP service?

This is because Stuart Chesire registered that FTP service as a *"proxy advertisement"*....

---

#### 5. Why did your query for the *`fffh.`* top level domain not work?

Mainly, because that domain most likely didn't register within a standard DNS server all the HTTP services which are hosted within its realm.

Maybe it doesn't even run a DNS server at all within its domain.

You would only discover those HTTP servers via `dns-sd -B _http._tcp local.`, if each webmaster of such a server would...

- ...run the appropriate `dns-sd -R ...` command in the background (if he has a Mac), or
- ...run the analog `avahi-publish -s ...` command (if he has Linux)

---

#### 6. Additional Info

BTW, you could browse and discover remote services without specifying the remote domain name, if you added the remote domain in your general DNS configuration as a *"browse domain"*. See this screenshot where I added `dns-sd.org` on a MacBook:

[image: DNS *Search Domain* "dns-sd.org" added in Mac OS X network configuration]

In this case you can simply run

`dns-sd -B _http._tcp`

to *also* get the remote HTTP services listed (as well as the local ones) instead of running

`dns-sd -B _http._tcp dns-sd.org`.